# SUM function in sql gives incorrect output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `##Temp2` with this data:

```
Rownumber   Percentage
    1   100.0000
    2   50.0000
    3   16.6667
    4   14.2857
    5   14.2857
    6   14.2857
    1   100.0000
    4   20.0000
    5   20.0000
    6   20.0000
    1   100.0000
    2   100.0000
    4   14.2857
    5   14.2857
    6   14.2857
```

I have this SQL query operated on above table:

```
 select SUM(Percentage) as SUM , @cnt as Count , (SUM(Percentage)/@cnt)
 as Percentage from ##Temp2 group By RowNumber order by Percentage desc
```

The  results are as follows:

```
SUM      Count        Percentage
200.0000    3          66.66666
50.0000     3         16.66667
34.2857     3         11.42857
34.2857     3        11.42857
34.2857     3        11.42857
16.6667     3         5.555567
```

`SUM` column is calculated wrong as clearly I can see.
**For example :** Value of `SUM` column should be `300` for rownumber `1` since I have used `Group by rownumber` and `SUM` aggregate function  on percentage column.

Why is that ?How do I deal with this to set it right ?

Comment: If your temp table has those 2 columns, and this is SQL Server, then your query should be giving you an error since it wouldn't let you order by `Percentage`

Comment: No errors at all at my end and I can do that. Yes, it is SQL server

Comment: I suspect your source table does not have the data you think it does (or there's more to your query than what was posted).  The sums would be right if the third "set" of numbers was missing.

Comment: @DStanley: I did select * from source table only .

Comment: @Lamak: This is inside of a Stored procedure. But I am not getting any errors for that. :/

Comment: I understand SUM function could not be the culprit here but I am pretty surprised with these results

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were giving `SUM(Percentage)/@cnt` a `Percentage` alias.

Comment: @Lamak, column aliases can be used in `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, I just commented that I hadn't seen the alias

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results on sqlfiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8cfc/6). Could you fork and edit to match the results that you see?

Comment: Anyway, you are using a global temp table inside a stored procedure, how can you know that the data inside isn't changing?

Comment: I am doing it on my local PC for testing purposes only. No other connections to it.

Comment: Actually,  these are the results from stored procedures that are executed in asynch using service broker. Could that be the reason ?

Comment: And at what point are you checking the data in the table?, just before performing the `SUM`?

Comment: @Simran, the query should work. At least sum.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That is done by design. just a value retrieved from some column in database based on requirement.

Comment: This Sql fiddle gives me different output http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c85af0/1

Comment: Okay, I have an intuition that it is because of procedures being called in asynch. Procedure inside of which these SP's are executed in asynch, looks like is returning results before all those SP's are done executing. It is pretty much the problem I guess.

Comment: If you're using this same table in several procedures running at the same time then of course your results can be a total mess.

Comment: A question, why are you using a global temporary table?

Comment: @JamesZ: Had changed local  to global for testing with different connections. Switched back to local now.

Comment: @JamesZ: It turns out using same table is not the right way then. Could you point the right ways to do it? I chose this as I am using an altogether different procedure to call these SP's to which I can not make any changes and this procedure is called from another procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table ##Temp2 (
            Rownumber int,
            Percentage float
        )
insert ##Temp2 select 1,   100.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    2,   50.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    3,   16.6667
insert ##Temp2 select    4,   14.2857
insert ##Temp2 select    5,   14.2857
insert ##Temp2 select    6,   14.2857
insert ##Temp2 select    1,   100.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    4,   20.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    5,   20.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    6,   20.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    1,   100.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    2,   100.0000
insert ##Temp2 select    4,   14.2857
insert ##Temp2 select    5,   14.2857
insert ##Temp2 select    6,   14.2857


select * from ##Temp2

declare @cnt int = 3

select  SUM(Percentage) as SUM, 
        @cnt as Count , 
        (SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Percentage 
    from ##Temp2 
    group By Rownumber 
    order by Percentage desc

drop table ##Temp2
```

Which returns:

```
SUM   Count Percentage
300     3   100
150     3   50
48.5714 3   16.1904666666667
48.5714 3   16.1904666666667
48.5714 3   16.1904666666667
16.6667 3   5.55556666666667
```

Comment: No actually,I am not looking for Count(*) at all. cnt is a variable which has value supplied according to data we have. These are weights to calculate average and has nothing to do with number of tuples.

Comment: OK, I've changed it to reflect that.  Of course, now it is the exact same query that you initially posted, though I am getting different results with your same data.

Comment: One more change, so you can see that I'm using the same data that you supplied.  I'm guessing there's more to your initial query that is messing up your results.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It essentially is some initially query messing my results. Thanks